# number of servers and environments

Tags: sharepoint-server

Hi am new to SharePoint 2010 administration and would like to know how do we determine number of servers and environments like Dev,  SysT, UAT  and prod. What do you follow to set up the SQL server instances while setting up Farm . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its depend upon the requirement of one's company.

- Purpose of the SharePoint user
- Number of user
- Workload / traffic to the SharePoint
- Authneticatio
- Services Applications
- Amount of Data.
  You have to go with [Capacity management and sizing for SharePoint Server 2013].

Please also check this [Technical diagrams for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199.aspx). This will give you complete understanding about the farms.
[1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199.aspx)

For Dev and QA usually lower requirement then prod.

Comment: Thank u Waqas is it same thing for SharePoint 2010 as well?..can a single SQL Server instance can share two sharepoint farms? incase of SQL server 2008r2 and SharePoint 2010..

Comment: Almost, but check technet page n go to older version....yes you can share one sql server among two farms,but performance may vary due to hardware...

Comment: But as of msdn it shows that in terms of production SharePoint should have seperate SQL. Don't mind if am wrong I just want to know things.. Thank you.

Comment: For prod yes, but u can have single sql with multiple sp farms in developing n qa....as I said due to performance msft not recommended that approach in production

Comment: Hi Waqas what kind of performance issues we may face if we do so ..is it regards to the application downage??

Comment: SQL server is high CPU & Memory lover, if you have two farm's db on the same server and in a given sitution one farm is under heavy load / or some other reason grab all resources from the server then the 2nd farmw ill go down.

Comment: Is there any msdn or link which shows the recommendations when we are building new SharePoint 2010 farms in terms of SQL  server? and can we use SQL Server 2012 for SharePoint 2010 which is already having SQL Server 2008

Comment: read this blog...http://tihomirignatov.blogspot.com/2010/12/sharepoint-2010-capacity-planning-and.html

Comment: Thanks Waqas ...that was a lot information from you ..helped me lot..

Comment: No problem, we are here to help each other....upvote will give me more confidence.